# How do I drop a picture that is in my local drive into an html file?

Tags: html, image

So I am trying to make a website with HTML and I wanna insert a picture that's on my desktop, only I can't find the URL to the picture, can someone tell me how I write that picture from my desktop into my HTML file? Line of code:

```
<a href="Picture.jpg">
    <img alt="Ismail" src="Picture.jpg" />
</a>
```

Comment: What is the point of this? If it's on your desktop, it will only be available to you?

Comment: Well, i dont really understand it :) im kinda new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Images in Another Folder**

If not specified, the browser expects to find the image in the same folder as the web page.

However, it is common to store images in a sub-folder. You must then include the folder name in the src attribute:

```
<img src="/images/html5.gif" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:128px;height:128px;">
```

Comment: So, if i'm right, i have to make a subfolder, and add that piece of code? (in my own way ofcourse), also, if i'm done with that site, can i make i public for anyone to see?

Comment: And i'll have to put the picture into the brackets folder, right?

Comment: 1.If the `yourfile.html` and `yourpic.gif` are in the folder you can write `<img src="yourpic.gif" alt="Picture Icon" style="width:128px;height:128px;">` if they aren't in the same folder you should write the whole path. 

2.you should upload the picture the the server if you want it public

Comment: Thanks, you helped me out really much :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear :)